# Getting Post Data at Jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey

Somebody will post data as like that:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/uno/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
 {"id" : "TestDoc2", "hry" : "go"}
]'
```

How can I get that data within my Jersey based Java application?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Here is a bean to match the `JSON` you posted:

```
public class Foo {
  String id;
  String hry;

  ...getters and setters...
}
```

And a basic resource listening on the paths your example is trying to `curl`:

```
@Path("/uno")
public class MyResource {

  @POST
  @Path("/json")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
  public void postJSON(List<Foo> fooList) {
    ...do whatever you need to
  }
}
```

Hope this helps